# Creating Web Sql table with javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite

my command does not work and I can not figure out why.
DB opens fine, but when comes to creating a table it does not processes it.

```
 var createtable2 = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS offlineCabinDefects (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Airline TEXT, Tail TEXT, FlightNumber TEXT,ActionDate TEXT,CabinArea TEXT,CabinItem TEXT, UnserviceableFlag TEXT, RowNumber TEXT,SeatNumber TEXT, Description TEXT, Revision TEXT, UserName TEXT, Password TEXT)';
var db = openDatabase('new', '1.0', 'Defect DB', 65536);
 db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(createtable2);
    });
```

I have used the same code, but with less columns and it worked, but for some reason this many columns does not.

Answer (score 0):

Web SQL is [deprecated](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/beyond-html5-database-apis-and-the-road-to-indexeddb/). You should either use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [`sql.js`](https://github.com/lovasoa/sql.js).